# python while loop converts temp

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

i have this code and want to run from 0 till input 28.3
but loop stops at 25 because it increments by 5. How can i get last loop stop at 28.3 (which is same as user input)

```
fah = 0

while(fah <= maxTemp):                          
    calcF = (fah-32)*5/9
    print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(fah,calcF))
    fah+=5
```

Comment: This is more a problem solving question than programming. Have you tried any changes and got results that would not help you deduce what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the calculation one more time after looping:

```
fah = 0
maxTemp = 28.3

while(fah < maxTemp):
    calcF = (fah-32)*5/9
    print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(fah,calcF))
    fah+=5
calcF = (maxTemp-32)*5/9
print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(maxTemp,calcF))
```

output:

```
 0.00 | -17.78
 5.00 | -15.00
 0.00 | -12.22
15.00 |  -9.44
20.00 |  -6.67
25.00 |  -3.89
28.30 |  -2.06
```

Comment: thank you so much, putting calculation in the bottom worked.

Comment: This violates the DRY principle

Answer (score 0):

You can increment `fah` by 0.1, instead of 5

```
fah += 0.1
```

This will give you 50x more output though.

Because of the way you are looping, the output will never contain that final 28.3 value though, since it increments after printing.  This can be fixed by your loop condition (and a bunch of other ways).

```
maxTemp = 28.3
fah     = 0
step    = 0.1

while(fah <= (maxTemp + step)):
    calcF = (fah-32)*5/9
    print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(fah,calcF))
    #fah += 5
    fah += step
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

What you're trying to do is a [do-while](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop) loop, which is not natively supported in Python. Here is a way to make it as so.

```
fah = 0
maxTemp = 28.3

while True:
    calcF = (fah-32)*5/9
    print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(fah,calcF))
    fah+=5
    if (fah > maxTemp):
        break
```

**Method 2**

Instead of `fah < maxTemp`, you can do the comparison `fah < (maxTemp + interval)` (where `interval=5` in your case).

```
fah = 0
maxTemp = 28.3
interval = 5

while fah < (maxTemp + interval):
    calcF = (fah-32)*5/9
    print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(fah,calcF))
    fah+=interval
```

**Method 3**

You can also use a for loop with `math.ceil(maxTemp)+interval`, at every interval of `interval`.

```
fah = 0
maxTemp = 28.3
interval = 5

for i in range(0, int(math.ceil(maxTemp)+interval), interval):
    calcF = (fah-32)*5/9
    print("%10.2f | %6.2f" %(fah,calcF))
```